# Update UITableview cell with new loaded content while scrolling

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, nsrunloop

I have a `UITableView`, I use the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` function to download an image for a specific cell. The image download is performed asynchronously and finishes after a short amount of time and calls a completion block after finishing. I set the cell content to the downloaded image inside the completion block, but it doesn't get updated until after the user finishes scrolling. I know that the reason is because the code should be running in `NSRunLoopCommonModes`, but I don't know how to do that in this case, any help is appreciated.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{

let dequeued  = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(imageFileCellIdentifier)
        let cell = dequeued as! ImageTableViewCell

    source.FetchImage(imageLocation, completion: { (image) in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { 
            cell.previewImage.image = image
            cell.previewImage.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: what type is source variable?

Comment: UI must be updated in main thread - use - dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { } to update UIs

Comment: @RJE , Somebody already pointed that out, I know that I have to be on the main thread, and I am, that is not the problem here.

Comment: @David its a custom class that loads images from a custom external accessory with an SD card.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{

let dequeued  = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(imageFileCellIdentifier)
        let cell = dequeued as! ImageTableViewCell

    source.FetchImage(imageLocation, completion: { (image) in

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
             cell.previewImage.image = image
             cell.previewImage.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
        })


    })
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this does not solve the problem, the code is already running on the main queue but I need it to be in NSRunloopCommonModes

Answer (score 0):

UI must be updated in main thread

You can use something like this to update imageView - coz asynchronous completion block may not call within main thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    cell.previewImage.image = image
    cell.previewImage.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
}
```

to update UIs

And also it is better if you check that the cell you are updating is the correct cell. Because when download completed(asynchronously) cell may be scrolled-out of the view and that cell may be allocated to another row. In that case you are setting the image to a wrong cell.

eg.

```
if cell.imageName == 'downloaded_image_name' {
    // do update
}
```

Comment: Somebody already pointed that out, I know that I have to be on the main thread, and I am, that is not the problem here.